# Chrome extension: Execute only on current domain name once browser action is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is my scenario: By clicking the browser icon, I create a sidebar (html and css) next to the whole page, thus creating two columns (one is my sidebar, the other one is the actual page).

What I to achieve is having the sidebar stay when I reload the page or navigate to another page WITHIN the same domain. What I have right now is just the creation of the sidebar, but I have to click the browser action every time I navigate or reload the web page.

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "apdrop",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "first prototype for apdrop extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "apdrop"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*/",
    "https://*/*/"
  ]
}
```

Background.js

```
function injectedScript(tab, method){
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file:"style.css"});
    //chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file:"bootstrap.css"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: 'jquery-2.1.1.min.js'});
    //chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: 'bootstrap.min.js'});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: 'inject.js'});
}

function click(tab){
    console.log("browser action clicked");
    injectedScript(tab, 'click');
    //alert("action button was clicked");
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(click);
```

Inject.js

```
var ev = $("body > *");
    if (!document.getElementById('contentxf343487d32')) 
    {
        ev.wrapAll("<div id='insidecontent65675f526567'>");
        $("#insidecontent65675f526567").wrapAll("<div id='contentxf343487d32'>");

        $("<div id='sidebar343gf87897fh'><div id='insidesidebar87678bbbb'><p>this is my name</p></div></div>").insertBefore("#contentxf343487d32");
    }
    else
    {       
        $("#sidebar343gf87897fh").remove();
        $("#insidecontent65675f526567").unwrap();
        $("#insidecontent65675f526567 > div").unwrap();
    }
```

Hope this helps clarify a bit more.

Comment: I assume you have the following setup: `<all_urls>` or equivalent permission in the manifest, and programmatic injection via `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. Please edit your question with details of how you inject the script and what happens on `browserAction` click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest strategy would be to save state in domain's `sessionStorage` and have a "detector" script that re-injects your UI.

1. Add setting the state in your content script:

   ```
   // inject.js
   if (!document.getElementById('contentxf343487d32')) 
   {
       // ...
       sessionStorage["contentxf343487d32"] = true;
   }
   else
   {       
       // ...
       sessionStorage["contentxf343487d32"] = false;
   }
   ```
2. Add a "detector" script:

   ```
   // detect.js
   if(sessionStorage["contentxf343487d32"])
   {
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage({injectSidebar: true});
   }
   ```
3. Always inject the script on page load, via the manifest (and change to a better permission):

   ```
   "content_scripts" : [
       {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["detect.js"]
       }
   ],
   "permissions": [
       "background",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
   ]
   ```
4. In the background, inject the script upon message:

   ```
   // background.js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function (message, sender, sendResponse){
       if(message.injectSidebar)
       {
         click(sender.tab);
       }
   });
   ```

If you need more persistence than `sessionStorage` provides, use `localStorage`. If you need a different logic, you can still use this skeleton of a detector signalling the background.

Comment: _"Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."_ -- D. Knuth

Comment: Would this strategy not interfere with other tabs already opened or newly created tabs? I am note sure if what you wrote actually works only for current domain of the page, not of other tabs.

Comment: In case of `sessionStorage`, it will be limited to one tab as per [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage). Note that content scripts do not share `*Storage` with the extension, but with the page, so page's domain applies.

Comment: One last thing, the "chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(click)" should be removed right?

Comment: No! It's still the main way to toggle things. The detector script just fakes this event when a page loads and the conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Awesome! Your strategy/solution works like a charm. Thanks Xan!